# how to get string from approot(site url)?

Tags: haskell, yesod

i looked though yesod tutorial and source code but find no way to do such trival thing...must i use pattern match?

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.2.2/docs/Yesod-Core.html

source:

```
-- | How to determine the root of the application for constructing URLs.
--
-- Note that future versions of Yesod may add new constructors without bumping
-- the major version number. As a result, you should /not/ pattern match on
-- @Approot@ values.
data Approot master = ApprootRelative -- ^ No application root.
                    | ApprootStatic !Text
                    | ApprootMaster !(master -> Text)
                    | ApprootRequest !(master -> W.Request -> Text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `getUrlRender` from `Yesod.Core.Handler` or maybe `renderRoute` from `Yesod.Core`?

Comment: renderRoute only get relative url string from (Route a) ,but i want to get the whole absolute route..which is easy to embed into hamlet by @{} notation...

Comment: @doofin Here's what I've used (sorry if it doesn't fit your usecase): https://git.gnu.io/snowdrift/snowdrift/blob/master/tests/TestImport.hs#L548 https://git.gnu.io/snowdrift/snowdrift/blob/master/Handler/User.hs#L87 Both give an absolute url.

Comment: i see : render :: RenderRoute App => Text -> Route App -> Text
render appRoot = ((appRoot <> "/") <>) . T.intercalate "/" . fst . renderRoute                   ,but the type of approot function defined in yesod typeclass is not text..so what do u give to render function as the first argument? we can define a approot string of course,but this should already be done by yesod

Comment: @doofin `getUrlRender` gets the whole absolute route.